# Creating a .bat for screenshotting folders with ffmpeg

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, batch

I was looking for a .bat script for ffmpeg and came across [this thread on the forum here](https://superuser.com/a/1346333/1816537).

The code in question is

```
for %%F in (*.mp4) do (
If not Exist "%%~nF" MkDir "%%~nF"
ffmpeg -i %%F -r 1 -qscale:v 2 %%~nF\%%~nF-%%3d.jpg
)
```

FFMPEG is added to PATH, when I try to use this batch script on a folder the folders are created but no images appear.

In addition to getting the screenshots to appear in the folders, I'd just like to know if there's a better command for including multiple file formats - most of my content is in .mkv but here are random other formats as well.

would

```
for %%F in (*.mp4, *.mkv) do (
```

work for that?

I forgot to add, I'm not sure if it matters but the files are on external hard drives (not C:/), the script ran from within the folder that contains the files.

My apologies for creating a new post, I would have commented in that one and hoped for the commenter to respond, but I am a new account and didn't have the reputation.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The line with `ffmpeg` of the copied code is not save for path/filenames containing spaces.

Change the `ffmpeg`-line to the following:

```python
ffmpeg -i "%%F" -r 1 -qscale:v 2 "%%~nF\%%~nF-%%3d.jpg"
```

Please note the added quotations.

---

> I'd just like to know if there's a better command for including multiple file formats - most of my content is in .mkv but here are random other formats as well.
>
> would
>
> ```
> for %%F in (*.mp4, *.mkv) do (
> ```
>
> work for that?

*Why don't you test this known code by yourself? Testing this is absolutely trivial. Questions you easily can solve by yourself is not polite. — It prohibits us to help others.*

But yes:  To catch different file formats by their extension, the simplest change to the code is your own suggestion.

---

##### Update

> Unfortunately I changed the line but it's still closing immediately and nothing is appearing in the folders

This hints to me that you start the batch by a shortcut icon, but not from within an open command shell.

To see the code working, please open a command shell and start the script as a shell command. PLease copy the output as an update to your question.

Perhaps you want to generate a small test structure of your video collection to limit to a reasonable amount of output.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I wasn't able to test if it worked because I was unable to get any of the screenshots working in the first place :^) Since I was here I figured another related question wouldn't have been an issue, over cluttering up with multiple junk posts.

Comment: Thank you again for responding! I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I changed the line but it's still closing immediately and nothing is appearing in the folders.

     `for "%%F" in (*.mkv, *.mp4) do (`
     `If not Exist "%%~nF" MkDir "%%~nF"`
     `ffmpeg -i "%%F" -r 1 "%%~nF\%%~nF-%%3d.png"`
     `)`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Hi there, I've just found some time to go and take a look at this some more. Unfortunately, I've not made any headway whatsoever - the only information I get from using CLI is "%%F: No such file or directory", or "%%F" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: It may be a permissions error due to the files being on an external hard drive. Will try on C:/

Edit: It did not matter, same result via CLI.

Comment: Hopefully you are *not* using `%%F` directly on the command line. The doubled `%`  (`%%F`) is for the usage in a batch only. To use it on the command line reduce it to one `%`, so writing `for %F in ....`.